# Definition of complex derivative in polar coordinates.

Tags: complex-analysis

Since my answer at the end depends on $\theta_0$, I can tell that I have an error somewhere but I cannot find it.  I am trying to compute the derivative of $z^2$ in polar coordinates.  I convert between Cartesian and polar with

\begin{equation}
x(r,\theta)=r\cos(\theta)~~, \qquad\qquad\text{and}\qquad\qquad y(r,\theta)=r\sin(\theta)~~.\nonumber
\end{equation}

I have

\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dz}\,z^2&= \lim\limits_{\substack{\Delta x\to0\\\Delta y\to0}}\dfrac{\big(x+iy+\Delta x+i\Delta y\big)^2-\big(x+iy\big)^2}{\Delta x+i\Delta y}\nonumber\\
&\nonumber\\
&=\lim\limits_{\substack{\Delta x\to0\\\Delta y\to0}}\dfrac{2x\Delta x+2ix\Delta y+2iy\Delta x-2y\Delta y+2i\Delta x\Delta y+\big( \Delta x\big)^2-\big( \Delta y\big)^2}{\Delta x+i\Delta y} ~~.\nonumber
\end{align}

Then

\begin{equation}
\Delta x=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}\,\Delta r+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\,\Delta \theta=\cos(\theta)\,\Delta r-r\sin(\theta)\,\Delta \theta~~,\nonumber
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\Delta y=\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}\,\Delta r+\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\,\Delta \theta=\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta~~,\nonumber
\end{equation}

When I plug everything in I get

\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dz}z^2&= \lim\limits_{\substack{\Delta r\to0\\\Delta \theta\to\theta_0}}\Bigg\{\dfrac{2r\cos(\theta)\big[\cos(\theta)\,\Delta r-r\sin(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]+2ir\cos(\theta)\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]}{i\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]}+...\nonumber\\
&\qquad\quad...+\dfrac{2ir\sin(\theta)\big[\cos(\theta)\,\Delta r-r\sin(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]-2r\sin(\theta)\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]}{i\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]}+...\nonumber\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad...+\dfrac{2i\big[\cos(\theta)\,\Delta r-r\sin(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big] }{i\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]}+...\nonumber\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad...+\dfrac{\big[\cos(\theta)\,\Delta r-r\sin(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]^2-\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]^2 }{i\big[\sin(\theta)\,\Delta r+r\cos(\theta)\,\Delta \theta\big]}\Bigg\}~~.\nonumber\\
&\nonumber\\
&= \dfrac{2r\cos(\theta)\big[-r\sin(\theta)\theta_0\big]+2ir\cos(\theta)\big[r\cos(\theta) \theta_0\big]+2ir\sin(\theta)\big[-r\sin(\theta)\theta_0\big]}{ir\cos(\theta)\theta_0}+...\nonumber\\
&\qquad\quad...+\dfrac{-2r\sin(\theta)\big[r\cos(\theta)\theta_0\big]+  2i\big[-r\sin(\theta)\theta_0\big]\big[r\cos(\theta)\theta_0\big]  }{ir\cos(\theta)\theta_0}+...\nonumber\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad...+\dfrac{\big[-r\sin(\theta) \theta_0\big]^2-\big[r\cos(\theta)\theta_0\big]^2 }{ir\cos(\theta)\theta_0}~~.\nonumber
\end{align}

I can tell right away that it is wrong because of these $\theta_0^2$ terms.  Obviously this is not an issue if $\Delta\theta\to0$.  However, I am not clear why $\Delta\theta$ has to go to zero since $z=0$ for any $r=0$.  Thanks.

Comment: This might be totally stupid as I could be mixing up $r,\theta$ wrongly with $\Delta r,\Delta \theta$.  If so, please let me know.

Comment: You only need to have $\Delta r\to 0$. That is equivalent to “$\Delta x\to 0$ and $\Delta y\to 0$”. The behavior of $\Delta \theta$ is completely unconstrained. That said, I haven’t looked through your work to see what might be wrong. But you certainly don’t need to have that $\lim \Delta\theta$ exists.